# I want to spend a dictionary to the template with web.py

Tags: python, django, dictionary, web.py, tweepy

I want to spend a dictionary to the template, but the prints nothing for me , and if I print before passing the dictionary access the coordinates.

```
tweets = tweetCol.find({"contenido" : contenido, "direccion" : direccion,"radio" : radio} )
    for t in tweets:
        print t['CoordenadasTweet']
    return render.app(form, centro,tweets)
```

This print:

This print is as i want to do in the template.

```
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB4_8JwKM_0AkAM0YJouBBg0wYhWs8dHpY&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng($direccion)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

    $for t in tweets :
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng($t['CoordenadasTweet'][0], $t['CoordenadasTweet'][1]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title:"$t["ciudadUsuario"]"     
            });
    }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```